# Phusion Passenger http to https results in redirect loop

Tags: nginx, docker, passenger

I'm trying to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS but end up in a redirect loop.

What have I done wrong or am I missing?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  return 301 https://test.website.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name test.website.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3;

  root /home/app/webapp/public;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/tls.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/tls.key;
}
```

Still not sure what is going wrong. Without the redirect. HTTP and HTTPS works. Is there something the HTTPS server not doing on redirect.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.website.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3;

  root /home/app/webapp/public;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name test.website.com;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.3;

  root /home/app/webapp/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/tls.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/tls.key;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing I'm missing the location directive and proxy pass. I will investigate further. Not sure which URL the proxy pass should be using.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your application is misconfigured and still issuing redirects back to `http`.

Your `http` to `https` rule always sends it back to the root. You should do two things.

Forward from `http` to `https` while maintaining the original URI:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) for details.

And use a browser side toolbox or plug-in to analyse the HTTP `Location:` response header to identify the nature of this redirect loop. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) for more.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll investigate further.

Comment: I've checked the application and that seems ok. I've added my config above that works for HTTP and HTTPS. The location header is showing the correct redirect url. Not sure what is going wrong with the 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code as given on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/http-https-redirect-positive-ssl-on-nginx

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.domain.com;

       [....]
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Tried that, one of the first things I saw on Google. I'm leaning towards it being a Passenger issue. Will try a plain Nginx install later this evening. @Mayank, thanks for suggesting.